# Overriding methods in subinterfaces

Tags: java, interface

I had some discussion with my colleagues about superinterfaces and subinterfaces. The problem is the following:
we implementing our own "filesystem" in NIO and my colleague think there are some errors in the javadocs of java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributeView and his subinterface PosixFileAttributeView.
The javadocs says BasicFileAttributeView.name() should return "basic" but the javadocs says PosixFileAttributeView.name() should return "posix".
My colleague said PosixFileAttributeView.name() can't return "posix", it had to return "basic" because of the api contract in BasicFileAttributeView.
Is he right?

Cheers
Huu Chi Vu

Comment: `PosixFileAttributeView.name()` does not return anything, it is just an interface. An implementation of `PosixFileAttributeView` may return anything you like from its `name()` implementation. Although it would be wise return the recommended 'posix' unless you know better.

Comment: Sorry for beeing so unclear. The question: is there an error in the javadocs as my colleague said. Because the doc in BasicFileAttributeView.name() said it should return "basic". So suppose you use BasicFileAttributeView in a method m(BasicFileAttributeView view){ view.name()} and has an instance _posix of a class implementing PosixFileAttributeView. Using m(_posix), would you expect view.name() returns "basic" or "posix" after reading the javadocs?

Comment: Both Views are interfaces (so they do not have any implementation). An implementation of BasicFileAttributeView would be expected to return "basic" for name(). An implementation of PosixFileAttributeView would be expected to return "posix" for name().

Comment: Maybe the problem I have is hard to describe. Because I just don't see any problem with the javadocs as my colleague does. He sees that the "api contract" specified classes implementing BasicFileAttributeView.name() should return "basic" so classes imlementing subinterfaces of BasicFileAttributeView like PosixFileAttributeView also should returns "basic" and not "posix" as specified in the javadocs of PosixFileAttributeView.name().

Comment: Your colleague is incorrect. The subinterface is defining its own contract for name().

Comment: @JamesB that is also what I think, but I'm unsure who is right, because I never use subinterfaces before.

Answer (score 0):

Both Views are interfaces (so they do not have any implementation).

An implementation of BasicFileAttributeView would be expected to return "basic" for name().

An implementation of PosixFileAttributeView would be expected to return "posix" for name().

PosixFileAttributeView is defining its own contract for name() so implementations of it should return "posix", not "basic" as your colleague is suggesting.

**EDIT:**

Your colleague is saying:

> He sees that the "api contract" specified classes implementing BasicFileAttributeView.name() should return "basic"

This is true.

He is also saying:

> so classes implementing subinterfaces of BasicFileAttributeView like PosixFileAttributeView also should returns "basic" and not "posix"

But PosixFileAttributeView is not implementing BasicFileAttributeView, it is extending it and redefining the contract for name().

Comment: Ok but what happen with a class implementing both BasicFileAttributeView and PosixFileAttributeView (even when it makes no sense). Which contract should it use now?

Comment: As much as it makes no sense, it should honour PosixFileAttributeView and it has overridden the contract for name(), originally defined in BasicFileAttributeView.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to see it from a more formal standpoint:

A class Foo implementing an interface Bar makes the following claim true:

> Foo IS-A Bar.

A interface Bar extending and Interface Baz makes the following claim true:

> Bar IS-A Baz.

"IS-A" is transitive, thus:

> Foo IS-A Baz.

In your case this means:

1. every implementation of BasicFileAttributeView must return "basic" when calling "name()"
2. every implementation of PosixFileAttributeView must return "posix" when calling "name()"

As every implementation of PosixFileAttributeView is also an implementation of BasicFileAttributeView (see above why), it must return "basic", thus PosixFileAttributeView is breaking API contract of BasicFileAttributeView.

This means:

**PosixFileAttributeView IS-NOT-A BasicFileAttributeView**.

One simple example, from the API this would be valid (but not advised) to do:

```
public boolean isSupported(FileAttributeView view){
  switch(view.name()){
    case "basic": //do some basic view stuff
                  return true;
    case "foo": //I support foo view too
                return true;
    default: return false;
  }
}
```

Think your colleague is right then.